# PHP mail send MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi Im using PHP mail to send messages from a DB> However with the code below I get multiple emails from a single query. Hence if a query has 10 results, I get 10 emails. How can sort this out. Thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT stimee, pango,kembo FROM layla";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



    $msg = "Time: " . $row["stimee"]. " - pango: " . $row["pango"]. " " . $row["kembo"] . "<br>";


    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: Benge Man <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 


    mail("example@yahoo.com","Notification",$msg,$headers);

  }
  } else {
   echo "0 results";
  }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: Move the `mail` outside of the `while` loop. Move the `$headers` outside the while as well and then have the `$msg` concatenate.

Comment: mail command is inside your loop. you need to accumulate your maildata in an array in the while loop and then use `mail` outside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the message inside the loop, but send the mail afterwards. That way, you get one mail with all the data in it.

```
$msg = "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  // append data of each row to $msg.
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $msg .= "Time: " . $row["stimee"]. " - pango: " . $row["pango"]. " " . $row["kembo"] . "<br>";
  }

  // After all the rows are fetched, send the message.
  $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
  $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
  $headers .= 'From: Benge Man <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

  mail("example@yahoo.com","Notification",$msg,$headers);
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send the mail outside of your loop like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT stimee, pango,kembo FROM layla";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



$msg = "Time: " . $row["stimee"]. " - pango: " . $row["pango"]. " " . $row["kembo"] . "<br>";


$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Benge Man <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 




  }
mail("example@yahoo.com","Notification",$msg,$headers);
  } else {
   echo "0 results";
  }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```